# How to logout user after disconnect or browser close?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, single-page-application

I'm trying to work a solution to timing out a user from my web application. I'm currently using ng2-idle and it seems to only work on the active window rather than be tracked server side (angular server webpack)

I need to handle these two events in addition to the one above:

- On Browser Close
- On Connection loss (Power cut, blue screen, etc..)

After testing, my timeout was not being tracked after closing the window. Ng2-idle has modules such as keepalive but I'm not exactly sure how to use it and if it solves my problem

I will provide code if needed

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, that the client and server are communicating in stateless manner. This means if the user disconnects no body knows.

If your browser has a hook function for closing or navigating to another site you could use that and send the logout request.

Another thing which relavant is session expiration, you should use that. If you are using a token you will need to blacklist that, as non active as long as the session may be valid (or however).

Disconnect is a major problem (session expiration tried to solve that somehow).
A more sophisticated way if it is really crucial to log out on disconnect you may need to use websockets or http long polling. You would need to send a heartbeat and if it's not responding, after some time you will automatically logout the user.

Hope these thoughts kind somehow help.

Comment: " You would need to send a heartbeat" Exactly! But how can I ensure that my listener is always running and actively tracking that heartbeat? My major issue is the variables that are tracking the timeout are destroyed along with the session close.

Comment: Take a deeper look into Websockets. You would just need to assure a connection and send a heartbeat if it won't respond, that when the session is over. Simple as that. Leaving the page and so on also leads to that case, so you have just handled different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

when you close your browser session will destroy.So you can use session to logout.

Comment: What about the case of a user connecting to my server? I want to time out his session 30 minutes after he closes the browser or in case of a crash. How can I declare a global variable and update it based on user activity? If the user goes idle (or in case of a crash), the timer will start 30 minutes. After 30 minutes the user will timeout and disconnect automatically.

I'm using ng2-idle, but after closing the session the timer is also destroyed along with it. I'm not able to keep track of the timeout on my server